# how can i execute mysql insert statement synchronously inside javascript map

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, async-await

I want to insert rows in an array and do something with the result but it seems everything gets executed asynchronously. this is my code. I expect the console.log to have values but is empty every time, it seems i cannot get my code to execute this in a synchronous way

```
    const resultMap = []
    const result = await anArray.map(async (o) => {
        const result = await connection.query('insert into (...) values (...)', [...]);
        resultMap.push(result);
        console.log('----> pushed', )
    });

    console.log(resultMap);
```

output:

```
    []
    ----> pushed
    ----> pushed
    ----> pushed
    ----> pushed
    ----> pushed
    ----> pushed
    ----> pushed
```

Comment: it us possible to do so, but it is easier to to do it asynchronous. because you would have to stop all activioties for the time the server to complete the task, that should be really good thought about

Comment: well, im not looking for easier solution as i'm trying to solve a problem,  i need to have all the inserted ids before continuing on

Comment: there are some tutorials for that handle like this https://medium.com/@patarkf/synchronize-your-asynchronous-code-using-javascripts-async-await-5f3fa5b1366d

Comment: that example shows how you can rewrite your code, you need to read it carefully, as it shows you have to rewrite much miore that 1one function.

Comment: the question is that async await is not working inside a javascript map, the tutorial shows you how to use async await

Answer (score 0):

The map with async return an array of promises you have to resolve.

```js
function asyncTask (arg){
    return new Promise((resolve)=>{resolve (arg)})
}


const resultMap = []
async function test (){
    const result = await Promise.all([1,2,3].map(async (item) => {
        const result = await asyncTask(item);
        resultMap.push(result);
        console.log('----> pushed', item)
    }));
    console.log(resultMap)
}

test()
```